# Struts2 action mapping issue

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, struts, tiles

**Hello everyone,**

it's not really an issue but I'd like to know how do I restrict the following behavior.

I have this set in my **stuts.xml** file.

```
<struts>
    <constant name="struts.enable.DynamicMethodInvocation" value="false" />
    <constant name="struts.devMode" value="false" />
    <constant name="struts.custom.i18n.resources" value="ApplicationResources" />

    <package name="default" extends="struts-default" namespace="/">
        <result-types>
            <result-type name="tiles" class="org.apache.struts2.views.tiles.TilesResult" />
        </result-types>

        <action name="blue">
            <result name="success" type="tiles">/blue.tiles</result>
        </action>

        <action name="yellow">
            <result name="success" type="tiles">/yellow.tiles</result>
        </action>

        <action name="red">
            <result name="success" type="tiles">/red.tiles</result>
        </action>
     </package>
</struts>
```

Now what bothers me, is that the actions are acessible like this:

```
http://localhost:port/blue
http://localhost:port/yellow
http://localhost:port/red
```

but you can also access them like this..

```
http://localhost:port/yellow/blue/
http://localhost:port/red/blue/yellow
```

so ti triggers all the actions mentioned after "/".

I want to prevent this from happening , so I'd like to know if there's any way to restrict it?

thanks in advance,
Alex

Comment: ok, I have updated my first post.

Comment: Check `struts.mapper.alwaysSelectFullNamespace` property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `web.xml` you might having an entry like this for the struts action mapping

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>struts2</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

As per the servlet specification `A string beginning with a ‘/’ character and ending with a ‘/*’ suffix is used for path mapping`

So if you want to give the absolute url mapping, then you have to specify them like below

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>struts2</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/blue</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>struts2</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/yellow</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>struts2</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/red</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

If you are using struts 2.1.7 or more then you can add a exclude pattern like below

```
<constant name="struts.action.excludePattern" value="/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/.*"/>
```

Comment: For the tiles to be working , I guess I should then map them like this..
  <action name="">
   <result name="success" type="tiles">/red.tiles</result>
  </action>

Comment: actually it does not work..I'm not sure why it keeps saying ..."There is no Action mapped for namespace [/] and action name [red] associated with context path [/test]."

Comment: what about the actions should I keep them in the same package (for anmespace="/")

Comment: @Wracker you can have them in the same package. Have you tried with the exclude pattern ? It will solve your issue if you are using struts version 2.1.7 or more

Comment: yes it's working, although it's not executing my old actions like "GetMyReports" and so on.. tried making the regular expresion case insensitive ("/([a-z0-9]+)/i.*")but it didn't help..any dieas?

Comment: ok I have sorted it now.. thanks for all your help..it's greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is technically correct answer but not the best solution to the OP problem.